# AMP analytics - link tracking, track which links/data attributes were clicked

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I have implemented AMP analytics and a couple of events, it's working fine but I'm wondering how I could capture the destination of a clicked link.

If I have a link like this:

```
<a rel="nofollow,noopener" data-item="ShopName" data-product="ProductName" class="link-price" target="_blank" href="ShopURL">ShopName</a>
```

I track it like this:

```
"article prices": 
            {
                "on": "click",
                "selector": ".link-price",
                "request": "event",
                "vars": 
                    {
                        "eventCategory": "Prices",
                        "eventAction": "<I WOULD LIKE SHOPNAME HERE",
                        "eventLabel": "<I WOULD LIKE PRODUCTNAME HERE>"
                    }                   

            }
```

I would be tempted to put some javascript in there but javascript is not allowed.

Is there any possibility to track data attributes and urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data attributes in HTML:

```
data-vars-my-label="ProductName1"
```

and your config JSON:

```
"vars": {
    "event_label": "${myLabel}",
    ...
```

See https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/analytics-vars.md